# grab int passed by get method in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have setup a a delete button to delete a row in db. It takes id as parameter with get method.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="teacherDelete.jsp?=<%=t.getId()%>">Delete</a>
```

This is my code `teacherDelete.jsp` for grabbing the `id` and delete a row:

```
        <% 

        if (request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
                TeacherDAO tdao = new TeacherDAOImpl();
                Teacher t = new Teacher();
                t.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));                            
                tdao.delete(t);
           // New location to be redirected
           String site = new String("teachersShow.jsp");
           response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
           response.setHeader("Location", site);                     
            }
    %>
```

I'm getting `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` error with `HTTP Status 500`.

How can I grab the incoming parameter and pass it to my method ?

Answer (score 1):

before you convert to int you should check whether it contains null or not

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="teacherDelete.jsp?=<%=t.getId()%>">Delete</a>
```

sohould be

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="teacherDelete.jsp?id=<%=t.getId()%>">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed the parameter id `teacherDelete.jsp?=` in your code.

```
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="teacherDelete.jsp?id=<%=t.getId()%>">Delete</a>
```